# Very short Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, germany

I am an overseas citizen living in UK, I applied for Schengen visa for Germany and was given 3 days!

My trip is three days, and I asked for a multiple entry visa, but they gave me only three days, starting from my arrival date and ending the day I leave. Now I am very stressed about what can I do if my return flight gets delayed?

Also, what are the regulations for visa expiry for Germany... Am I safe to stay until mid night of the expiry date?

Comment: Might help a bit more if we knew your nationality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds exactly the same as I heard from friends - showed three day return tickets for Canary Islands and received three day visas from Spain. I would not expect EU embassies to give longer visas than the return tickets, unless more proof or an explanation or a good EU travel history is provided. I think this is fair.

Please ensure that you take proactive steps as soon as you are informed of any flight delays. You would not want an overstay stamp on your passport!

Edit:

Save the email ID of the embassy.
If your flight is delayed beyond midnight, send an email to embassy. Then show the email to the exit immigration officer and request not to put an overstay stamp on your passport. Then for future visa applications, attach a printout of the email showing that "unstamped overstay" was due to aeroplane delay and had been immediately informed to the embassy.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the examplary "proactive steps"?

Comment: @gdrt good question! If my flight is delayed beyond midnight, I would send a quick email to embassy. Then for future visa applications, I will attach printout of the sent email showing that overstay had been immediately informed.

Comment: @ShumonSaha that would make a good addition to the answer.